# Test if service had been update inside method using Karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I wanna test if a service that I have in a component had update his attribute after calling a method. How can I do this?

```
//.ts
public makeSomething(obj:MyObj) {
     //set attribute on my service 
     this.myService.setAtt(true);
}


.spec.ts
  it('should set attrib true on my service ',async(() => {

      let myObj: MyObj;
      component.makeSomething(myObj);
      //should check here if my service has att true!!!!!
      //how??     
 }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to test if your service has been updated. What you should test is that your service method has been called.

You will test that your service has been updated in the tests of your service.

This is what unit testing is supposed to do : test a unit.

If you test that your service has been updated, you will have to update your tests everytime you change your service. Now imagine this service is used by 400 components, what will you do ? Edit all components ?

Simply test that the function has been called :

```
const spy = spyOn(component.myService, 'setAttr');
component.makeSomething(myObj);
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Comment: How do you use component.myService? It cannot be called directly

Comment: Use `component['myService']`, the array notation, or make your service public

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use `spyOn(...)` with `toHaveBeenCalled()` method to check the updated value after the call.

[Here's an example](http://tobyho.com/2011/12/15/jasmine-spy-cheatsheet/) on how to use it.

So in your `spec` file, it'll look like:

```
  it('should set attrib true on my service ',async(() => {

      let myObj: MyObj;
      spyOn(myService, 'myServiceMethod');
      component.makeSomething(myObj);

      expect(myService.myServiceMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
      // other checks here...
   }));
```

Don't forget to import your service in your `it` statement.

Comment: it('should set attrib true on my service ',inject([MyService], (myService: Myservice) =>{  dont work. Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: Is that the import that isn't working or the code inside the `it` statement itself?

Comment: the import itself

Comment: If this way isn't working for you, you can try to inject just before `let myObj: MyObj;` like that: `const myService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MyService);`